# AngularStrap TypeAhead works after I click around a bunch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I am trying to use [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads) TypeAhead.  The feature seems to work, but only after I click around a bunch (or so it appears).  I just have stubbed data now so I know it can't be time from pulling data from API, etc. If I put the data in a dropdown it is available immediately (only like 5 items right now). I am not sure if it is taking a while for the directive to be enabled or what.  Really good chance it is user error, just not sure what to look for.  I am not seeing anything in the chrome debugger.

html code snippet:

```
<section id="dashboard-view" class="mainbar" data-ng-controller="dashboard as vm">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selectedPart" ng-options="p.partNumber for p in vm.parts" placeholder="Enter Part" bs-typeahead>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Vendor Scripts

```
<!-- Vendor Scripts -->
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/toastr.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/spin.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/smart-table.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide a reproductible snippet/fiddle. Usually this "i click everywhere and somehow it works" is that one click trigged a ng-click, thus a digect cycle, which means you'd lack a scope.$apply. But again we need to see the bug to undderstand it

Comment: Hi florbion. Thanks.  I will try to get something stood up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue (or very similar) where the dropdown would only appear if I followed these steps...

1. Type the first few characters of a valid item in the list
2. Click out of the input box so that it loses focus
3. Click back into the input box so that it gains focus again

The workaround suggested by `metronomx` in [typeahead not displaying sometimes 2.2.1 #1588](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1588) resolved the issue for me...

> Add following css rule: input + .typeahead.ng-hide { display: block
>   !important; visibility: hidden !important; overflow: hidden; }

Also: You'll want to use `bs-options` instead of `ng-options` if you are using ng-strap 2.2.1 and Angular 1.3.15, as alluded to in [Angular-strap v2.2.1 not compatible with angular v1.3.15](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1606)

Comment: Thanks @racingcow I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Thanks, i was just struggling with the same issue :)